# CSS3 animation-delay causing issue in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, animation

Hi I am trying to animate my logo with CSS3 but I want it to be animated after a few secs so I am using the `animation-delay` property. It works perfectly fine on Chrome but in Firefox it does delay the animation, but the position it takes is the ending position of animation and then after the delay the animation starts.

HTML

```
<div class="logo"></div>
```

CSS

```
.logo {
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
transform: translate(25px,500px);
-webkit-animation: logo 3s 1;
-moz-animation: logo 3s 1;
-webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
-moz-animation-delay: 3s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes logo{
  0% {
    transform: translate(80px, 200px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(25px, 500px);
  }
}
@keyframes logo{
  0% {
    transform: translate(80px, 200px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(25px, 500px);
  }
}
```

Also this is the fiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/faax1zde/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the animation delay so much as it is that you are initializing the position in the wrong place using the initial `transform`.

Change `.logo { ... transform: translate(25px,500px); }` to `.logo { ... transform: translate(80px, 200px); }`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/faax1zde/7/)

To keep it in the final state, add `animation-fill-mode:forwards`

Also, some of your prefixes should be added/changed. For more information as to which prefixes for `transform`, `animation`, etc. you need, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25110511/2065702)

Comment: The thing is I do not want the position of the logo to reset I want it to be positioned here transform: translate(25px, 500px); and that is why on default I have set the position to this transform: translate(25px, 500px);. In your demo you can see when your animation ends it quickly goes to this transform: translate(80px, 200px); position.

Comment: @fahad.kazi Sorry, I didn't check at the end :) to fix that, just add `animation-fill-mode:forwards`. There is no need for javascript of any sort

Comment: I wasn't aware of this property and as things were working in chrome so I did not bother to dig in much deep into the topic. Thank you for letting me know that there is much more than I thought. I will learn more about CSS3. Once again thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

After trying almost everything I am switching to Jquery and this works across all browsers.

```
<div class="logo"></div>
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    left: 80px;
    top: 200px;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.logo').delay(3000).animate({
        'left': '25px',
        'top': '500px'
    }, 3000);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faax1zde/6/)

Comment: There is no need for javascript of any sort

Answer (score -1):

Try to add another keyframes:

```
@-moz-keyframes logo {
}
```

Comment: I have tried this already but it doesn't work also when I remove the the delay property the animation works as it should be but then again i need the delay.