# CSS3 keyframe animation which runs on hover

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I am trying to make a small keyframe animation.

When the user hovers on a button, I want the background image to move slightly to the right, then back again. So a little "bounce" movement.

In my first example I used a simple hover in CSS that changed the background position from 91% to 93% which results in movement when hovered.

However when I tried to do something similar, to use a *keyframe animation* called `nextarrow`, the animation doesn't run.

Here is a JSFiddle showing my working example (`button-one`) and my non-working example (`button-two`)

Where have I gone wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/franhaselden/Lfmegdn5/

```
.button-two.next:hover{
   -webkit-animation: nextarrow 1s infinite;
   -moz-animation: nextarrow 1s infinite;
   -o-animation: nextarrow 1s infinite;
   animation: nextarrow 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes nextarrow {
  0% {
    background-position: 91% center;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 93% center;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 91% center;
  }
}
```

Comment: you want exactly the same result as button 1?

Comment: Did you add all required browser prefixed versions for `@keyframes` (like `@-webkit-keyframes`)? Adding that makes it [work](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfmegdn5/3/) for me.

Comment: @NaeemShaikh not exactly the same. As written in my post (and as seen in the keyframes) I would like the BG to move to 93% and then back to 91%. Similar but not the same to button one.

Comment: It works fine for Chromium browser, I thing @Harry is right

Comment: Though I haven't voted to close yet. This is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110510/why-doesnt-css-feature-work-in-browser-but-works-in-others

Comment: I deleted my answer. This **is** a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alternative to @jbutler483's answer use [Prefix free: Break free from CSS vendor prefix hell!](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/)

```css
.button.next{padding:5% 20%;background-image:url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-right-128.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: 91% center;}

.button-one.next:hover{background-position: 98% center;}

.button-two.next:hover{
   animation: nextarrow 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes nextarrow {
  0%,100% {
    background-position: 91% center;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 93% center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
Simple hover version<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Next question" class="button button-one green next" />
<br /><br /><br /><br />
Bounce animation version<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Next question" class="button button-two green next">
```

**Note:** *you can combine 0% and 100% since they are the same:*

from

```
@keyframes nextarrow {
  0% {
    background-position: 91% center;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 93% center;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 91% center;
  }
}
```

to

```
@keyframes nextarrow {
  0%,100% {
    background-position: 91% center;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 93% center;
  }
}
```

or to this

```
@keyframes nextarrow {
  from,to {
    background-position: 91% center;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 93% center;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to prefix your keyframes as well:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/Lfmegdn5/4/)

```
@-webkit-keyframes nextarrow{ keyframe definition here}
@-moz-keyframes nextarrow{ keyframe definition here}
@-o-keyframes nextarrow{ keyframe definition here}
@keyframes nextarrow{ keyframe definition here}
```

for example

```css
.button.next{padding:5% 20%;background-image:url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-right-128.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: 91% center;}

.button-one.next:hover{background-position: 98% center;}

.button-two.next:hover{
   -webkit-animation: nextarrow 1s infinite;
   -moz-animation: nextarrow 1s infinite;
   -o-animation: nextarrow 1s infinite;
   animation: nextarrow 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes nextarrow {
  0% {
    background-position: 91% center;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 93% center;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 91% center;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes nextarrow {
  0% {
    background-position: 91% center;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 93% center;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 91% center;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes nextarrow {
  0% {
    background-position: 91% center;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 93% center;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 91% center;
  }
}
@keyframes nextarrow {
  0% {
    background-position: 91% center;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 93% center;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 91% center;
  }
}
```

```html
Simple hover version<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Next question" class="button button-one green next" />
<br /><br /><br /><br />
Bounce animation version<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Next question" class="button button-two green next">
```