# Is it possible to make a cube out of six iframes?

Tags: html, css, iframe

A client wants to make a cube out of iframes. In other words, each side of the cube would be a different webpage via an iframe. And the user's perspective would be from inside the box - ie. you'd be inside the box and each wall would be an iframe/webpage.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Anything is possible given enough time, money and Adderall.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871528/create-a-rotating-cube-with-only-css is probably a reasonable starting point.

Comment: I don't understand if the perspective is from inside the cube, and every iframe will be 100% height and 100% width of the viewport, then you only need 6 divs and a transition orden and animation between them, or I am missing something? I mean you can make it look like a cube when transitioning but don't actually need to arrange the divs into a cube.